# Prefixing and appending blocks of text to a list of files

Tags: scripting

I'm trying to prefix and append blocks of text to a list of files. Here is where I am so far. The sticking point is the `sed -i "1i \$prefix" "$file" &&` line. `sed` won't substitute the value of `prefix` in. I tried to follow various threads about this on unix.sx and a couple of other places, but just got a headache.

Can someone tell me how to fix this? If it is too complicated I'm Ok with using something else instead of `sed`.

This is closely related to [How do I append text to the beginning and end of multiple text files in Bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65510/4671), which is where I got the code below from. The difference is that the question does not cover expanding a variable, and also in my case the strings in question are multiline.

```
filelist=(foo.tex bar.tex)

prefix='\documentclass[12pt]{article}                                                                                                                                       
\usepackage{myarticle}                                                                                                                                                      
%\xpretocmd{\opening}{\insertname}{}{}                                                                                                                                      
\begin{document}                                                                                                                                                            
%\insertname                                                                                                                                                                
\begin{verbatim}'

suffix='\end{verbatim}                                                                                                                                                      
\end{document}'                                                                                                                                                                 

for file in "${filelist[@]}"; do
  sed -i "1i \$prefix" "$file" &&
  echo "$suffix" >> "$file"
done
```

Comment: See this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/45208/4873 and delete that backslash in front of `$prefix`. What is it for?

Comment: @angus I'm guessing you have in mind something like `for file in "${filelist[@]}"; do
  sed -i "1i $(echo -E "$prefix" | sed -e 's/\\/\\\\/g')" "$file" &&
  echo "$suffix" >> "$file"
done`, but this gives an error.

Comment: OK, I see why you had a backslash. It was part of the sed command; I missed it. You need to double it and add a new line after it: `1i\\ ` _NEWLINE_ `$(echo ...`. See the linked answer and write your `sed` line exactly as it is there, only add `-i` and change `5a` by `1i` and `$text` by `$prefix`. That's all.

Comment: I'll write it in an answer, it will be clearer.

Answer (score 2):

How about (assuming your shell has process substitution):

```
for file in "${filelist[@]}"; do
    cat <(printf "%s" "$prefix") "$file" <(printf "%s" "$suffix") > "$file"_$$\ 
     && mv "$file"_$$ "$file"
done
```

or, better, in Perl (untested):

```
perl -MTie::File -e '
    @ARGV//=<STDIN>;
    chomp(@ARGV);
    for(@ARGV){
        tie @lines,"Tie::File",$_;
        @lines=($ENV{prefix} @lines $ENV{suffix})
    }' "${filelist[@]}"
```

For an alternative approach, if the prefix and suffix are fixed, see the following question (which also happens to be about (La)TeX :) ):

- [extracting and copying parts of tex files into new tex files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66569/extracting-and-copying-parts-of-tex-files-into-new-tex-files/)

Comment: Hi Joseph. Thanks for the suggestions. The last one does indeed seem like a nice simple way to approach the problem.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Great. Let us know how things work out...

Comment: I found you link to "extractig and copying parts..." more useful.

Answer (score 2):

With zsh:

```
zmodload zsh/mapfile
for i ($filelist) mapfile[$i]="$prefix
$mapfile[$i]$suffix
"
```

With `ksh93` or `bash` (or `zsh`):

```
for file in "${filelist[@]}"; do
  {
    rm -- "$file" && {
      printf '%s\n' "$prefix"
      cat
      printf '%s\n' "$suffix"
    } > "$file"
  } < "$file"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

The case is similar to this: [Appending a string containing escape character with sed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45206/appending-a-string-containing-escape-character-with-sed)

I suggest the same answer (adapted):

```
for file in "${filelist[@]}"; do
  sed -i "1i\\
$(echo -E "$prefix" | sed -e 's/\\/\\\\/g' | sed -e '$! s/$/\\/')" "$file" &&
  echo "$suffix" >> "$file"
done
```

The `sed` command `i` requires each line except the last to be terminated with a backslash (this was missing from the referred answer). Also, backslashes need to be doubled, so `sed` won't try to interpret them. The `echo` outputs the contents of the variable `$prefix`. Next in the pipeline, the `sed` command doubles the backslashes. The second `sed` command adds backslashes at the end of every line except the last.

**EDIT** How the sed program `$! s/$/\\/` works:

First, the address `$` means to execute the command that follows on the last line. `$!` negates that, so the command will be executed on all lines except the last.

Then, the `s///` command does substitution. It will substitute the empty string at the end of the line, denoted by `$`, with a backslash. But the backslash is a special character, so we need to escape it with another backslash for `sed` to read it correctly.

Comment: Hi Angus, thanks for the helpful reply. Unfortunately, the backslashes at the ends of lines appears in the final output. Is it possible to suppress this? Also, could you reference some sed documentation that (a) `i` requires each line except the last the be terminated with a backslash and (b) that backslashes need to be doubled? Finally if you go into a little more detail on how `sed -e '$! s/$/\\/'` works, that would be helpful.

Comment: (a) -> http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Other-Commands.html#Other-Commands, (b) -> on the same page, see documentation for `a\ `. (c) see edited answer.

Comment: Hi Angus. Thanks for the references. These could reasonably be in the question, I think. However, I don't see any change in the code (unless I'm missing something). How can one get rid of the extra backslashes?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. There aren't extra backslashes in the output when I run the script exactly as written. Maybe you aren't using GNU sed?

Comment: `sed --version
GNU sed version 4.2.1`. What version are you using? In any case, odd. I'll check again in case I made a mistake.

Comment: 4.2.2. It shouldn't be any difference.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few choices, none of which use `sed`. I find that in general, trying to get `sed` to play nice with external variables is rarely worth the effort.

#### Shell

```
for file in "${filelist[@]}"; do 
  tmp=$(mktemp); 
  printf "%s\n%s\n%s\n" "$prefix" $(cat "$file") "$suffix" > "$tmp" && 
  mv "$tmp" "$file"; 
done
```

#### Perl/Shell

```
for file in "${filelist[@]}"; do 
  tmp=$(mktemp); 
  perl -lpe 'BEGIN{print $ENV{prefix}}END{print $ENV{suffix}}' $file 
  mv "$tmp" "$file"; 
done
```

#### Pure Perl

This one has the advantage of not relying on external modules:

```
perl -le 'foreach (@ARGV){
           open($f,"+<","$_"); @a=<$f>; 
           print $f "$ENV{suffix}\n@a$ENV{prefix}"
          }' "${filelist[@]}"
```

#### NOTE:

The variables need to be exported in order for the Perl solutions to work, otherwise, they won't be available in the `%ENV` hash.