# Find files and recursively append text to them

Tags: bash, find

I have been looking for an answer to this problem for a while: how can I use find append text to all hits? My original method was something like
`sudo find / -type f -name "*.py" -exec cat somecode.txt >> {} \;`
although all that did was create a file name `{}` filled with the contents of somecode.txt repeated one for each hit. I then tried running the command as
`sudo find / -type f -name "*.py" -exec echo somecode.txt >> {} \;`
although that had the same effect, just this time `{}` was filled with the string `somecode.txt` repeated once f
or every hit. Is there any other way to accomplish this, or am I just missing something fundemental?
**EDIT:**
My intended goal is for the contents of `somecode.txt` to be appended to every python file in the system.

Comment: See also [How to prepend a particular text file contents to every text file in a directory and its subdirectories?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/125421)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just `-exec` a shell for each argument:

```
find . -type f -name "*.py" -exec sh -c 'cat somecode.txt >> "$1"' -- {} \;
```

(Starting out without `sudo` and in a place other than `/` might be a good idea).

If you want to be extra efficient, you might want to try something like:

```
find . -type f -name "*.py" -exec sh -c '< somecode.txt tee -a "$@"' -- {} +
```